# Bash Command Substitution as Parameter

Tags: linux, bash, command, substitution

After I have been following down a challenging problem with my friends, I had an idea to make a blind command substitution.

This one with single quotes,

```
pid='1024 --help `touch /tmp/helw`' piduser=$(ps -ouser -p$pid h)
```

does not create the file /tmp/helw

But this one with double quotes,

```
pid="1024 --help `touch /tmp/helw`" piduser=$(ps -ouser -p$pid h)
```

creates the file.

My problem is, how can i make command substitution without let it run in pid - variable, but in piduser variable.

Comment: You would have to use `eval`, likely, but why do you care `touch` gets run before `piduser` is defined?

Comment: For that matter, what output from `touch` are you expecting to catch?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. What on Earth are you hoping to accomplish here?

Comment: It shall be a script testing. Normally piduser is being executed in script. And i have the only way to influence the pid by injection from outside.

Comment: I do not expect any outputs. But this one must be executed perfectly from inside so i get rid of that. Any execution like touch is welcome. It serves to be a test without seeing any messages.

Comment: There is no way to cause a variable expansion to execute code contained in the variable without the cooperation of the caller, if that's what you're asking. That would be a *ginormous* security problem.

Comment: Both approaches don't make any sense. You are assigning to the variable `pid` a string, which starts with the number 1024, followed by a space, followed by the string `--help`, and then some garbage. What point is it to give this string to the `-p` option of `ps`.

Comment: Likewise, I have to ask -- is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't. Separate actions can and should be separate actions.

```
touch /tmp/helw && ...
```

...but if for some odd reason this is actually necessary (I can't imagine why), anything done inside `$(...)` is a subshell and can be several commands.

```
pid='1024 --help ' piduser=$( touch /tmp/helw && ps -ouser -p$pid h )
```

Comment: Actually the piduser variable is in a script. for example called testme. pid="1024..." ./testme should make the effect. Command substitution should run in this script as posted at the beginning.